# get last primary key-not identity- inserted using a trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, primary-key

I have an insert trigger to insert the primary key(varchar) of a table.I want to get the last inserted primary key value.
these is my insert trigger

```
   ALTER TRIGGER dbo.equipment_insert_pk 
     ON  dbo.Equipment 
     INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @id int;
    declare @cat varchar(2);
    select @cat=CategoryID from INSERTED;
    select @id=cast(max(right(EquipmentID,4)) as int) from Equipment where CategoryID=@cat;
    set @id=isnull(@id,0)+1;
    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    insert into Equipment
    select CategoryID+right('0000'+cast(@id as varchar(4)),4)
    ,CategoryID
    ,Location
    ,Detail
    ,'../BarcodeImage/'+CategoryID+right('0000'+cast(@id as varchar(4)),4)+'.jpeg'  from INSERTED;

END
```

I tried to write a function to fetch the last inserted primary key value but it seems not to work..because there is no scope for "inserted" outside trigger.Help me..
I tried this code within trigger with output clause no result so far..

```
insert into Equipment 
    output INSERTED.EquipmentID into @Temp_Tbl
    select CategoryID+right('0000'+cast(@id as varchar(4)),4)
    ,CategoryID
    ,Location
    ,Detail
    ,'../BarcodeImage/'+CategoryID+right('0000'+cast(@id as varchar(4)),4)+'.jpeg'  from INSERTED;
```

Any help ??

Comment: You can use an `OUTPUT` clause outside of a trigger to capture the inserted value(s).  Aside: Triggers operate on sets of rows.  Your trigger code is assuming a single row is inserted.

Comment: Is your PK a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER with default of NEWID()? If so, why not just generate NEWID() first, store it in a variable in your INSTEAD OF trigger, and insert that value manually?

Comment: I have spotted one problem here: `select @cat=CategoryID from INSERTED;`. I think that this code will not work correctly if somebody will insert two rows with different `CategoryID` values using the same statement thus: `INSERT INTO dbo.Equipment (..., CategoryID, ...) VALUES (...,1,...), (...,2,...);`

Comment: @user92546 Is there any way to insert multiple rows..and the trigger to work correctly ?

Comment: @shanirafi - Instead of getting a single `CategoryID` from `INSERTED` you would typically write your `INSERT` in the trigger to base all of its calculations off `INSERTED` and any other needed tables.  That way the number of rows in `INSERTED` shouldn't matter.  If needed you could use a table variable, rather than a scalar, in your intermediate processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. I bumped into this exact same problem a few weeks ago.

I've tried many different ways - to no avail. Long story short - I ended up adding a new column with the type of `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` (guid)

So to use your example - let's say there's a column called `guid` in `dbo.Equipment`

Roughly, here's how you do it:

```
insert into Equipment 
    output INSERTED.EquipmentID, INSERTED.guid into @Temp_Tbl
    select CategoryID+right('0000'+cast(@id as varchar(4)),4)
    ,CategoryID
    ,Location
    ,Detail
    ,'../BarcodeImage/'+CategoryID+right('0000'+cast(@id as varchar(4)),4)+'.jpeg'
    ,NEWID() -- new column
```

from INSERTED;

Then you can query `dbo.Equipment` using `@Temp_Tbl.guid` to get the inserted id.
For example:

`SELECT EquipmentID FROM dbo.Equipment e WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @Temp_Tbl tt WHERE tt.guid = e.guid)`